# Aligning a table vertically and horizontally

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, align

I need to place a table in the centre of a page, here is the code for the table which just centres the table horizontally, but not vertically.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

\begin{center}

%Title
{\Large MA2MIP Assignment 2\par}

%Individual contribution table
\begin{tabular}{|c | c|}
        \hline
        Student Number & Individual Contribution \\ \hline \hline
        23008055 & \% \\ \hline
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ \hline         
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ \hline
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ \hline
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ \hline
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{titlepage}


\end{document}
```

Some help would be great.

Comment: Welcome! Use `\begin{table}[p]\centering` instead of the `center` environment.

Comment: Welcome! Good to see the code. Could you complete it with a minimal preamble and `\end{document}` so people can copy-paste-compile it to see the problem? Also, TeX doesn't spell properly so it won't recognise `\begin{centre}`.

Comment: @cfr I have edited the post

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{\fill}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c c}
\toprule
        Student Number & Individual Contribution \\ 
\midrule
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
        XXXXXXXX & \% \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\vspace*{\fill}
\end{document}
```

to obtain something more stylish.